# Accessing checkbox list's checkitem in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have checkboxes in html as follows:

```
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="ChkmemberId" value="D657868" onclick="javascript:saveJobDetails('D657868','1');BindGrid('','Edit');">D657868

<input type="checkbox" name="ChkmemberId" value="M78786" onclick="javascript:saveJobDetails('M78786','1');BindGrid('','Edit');">M78786

<input type="checkbox" name="ChkmemberId" value="D89798" onclick="javascript:saveJobDetails('D89798','1');BindGrid('','Edit');">D89798</td>
```

I wanted to access checked items of these in javascript.

I tried as follows:

```
 elm = document.getElementByName("ChkmemberId");

                if (elm != null) {

                    alert('1');
                    var checkBoxes = elm.getElementsByTagName("input");
                    var label = elm.getElementsByTagName("label");
                    alert('2');
                    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
                        if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true) {

                            userID = userID + checkBoxes[i].value + ",";
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

But its not working.

Please help me how can i access checkboxlist in javascript.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: Its not binding checked items in UserID as userID = userID + checkBoxes[i].value + ",";

Comment: even its not giving me alerts which i kept for testing

Comment: What is `userID`? Where is it declared and what is its initial value?

Comment: The method you're looking for is `getElementsByName()`, note the 's' in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get child elements from an element who hasn't got any child elements.

```
var checkBoxes = elm.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

You want to get all the elements with the same name. After that you want to loop trough them all and put the value in userId.

Try it with this code:

```
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName('ChkmemberId');
for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
        userID += checkBoxes[i].value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
var checks = document.getElementsByName("ChkmemberId"),
    check, parts = [],
    userID, i;

for (i = 0; i < checks.length; i += 1) {
    check = checks[i];
    if (check.checked) {
        parts.push(check.value);
    }
}

userID = parts.join(", ");
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EVQwc/